# How to mix sass and scss with webpack?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader

As the title.

Some of libraries I want to use (Ex: `font-awesome`) use `scss`, while I prefer writing style with `sass`

How can I configure my project with `webpack`?

My current setting

```
...
rules: [
  ...
  {
    test: /\.(c|sa|sc)ss$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'scss-loader',
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  }
]
...
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-app-rewired`. You can copy what I did in this [commit](https://github.com/Vaibhav/ReactReduxStarter/commit/84d12a093569442136f5f627e0abfc74bd9b4023)

Or if you want to directly change the webpack.config.js file then:

```
npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

and then in your webpack.config.js, add the following object in your rules array as shown below.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            ]
        }]
    }
};
```